# Identify who made the purchase PayPal - IPN

Tags: java, servlets, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am developing a Twitter web app in which users can buy packages of coins.

Once they click on a paypal button and wants to checkout, they are directred to enter their credentials and finalize the paypal. The PayPal server will then in turn send a HTTP to a backend servlet of mine (Im doing this in Java) with info about the transaction.

My problem here is that how do I know which user made the purchase? The thing is, the IPN message sent by the PayPal server contains a set of predefined parameters from their side. This means that I can not really identify which user made the payment!

Since this is a twitter application, no username/email/password is needed to register for the website.

All I need and want is a way to send the dbUserId of the user that is making the purchase to the paypal IPN request so that once PayPal sends the IPN POST I know who made the purchase and thus add the coins to his/her record.

I need all help please.

Thanks

Comment: We are partners...

Back to my question,

Let me give you a scenario so that you better understand:

1) User x clicks on PayPal button and wants to buy
2) User x enters the PayPal credentials and makes the payment, afterwhich PayPal sends an IPN message to our backend servlet.

Now, how do i know that it is user x that has made the transaction so that I can update the database record for user x??

Comment: They give you `payer_email` but you don't know the email since you only know Twitter id, right? So that is a pickle.

Comment: Yes.. but even if we are to assume that I have a normal website with the ordinary username/email/pass, there still can exist a scenario in which the user has one email for his account, and one completely separate for his paypal.

I was wondering maybe if there is a way to send the users dbId record along the request sent to paypal and thus it can be sent back or something?

Answer (score 2):

You can send your ID value in the "custom" parameter of your Standard button code or API requests.  This parameter allows you to store anything you want up to 256 characters, and that same value will be returned in IPN in the "custom" parameter as well.

Another option would be to save a local invoice/order record for the user prior to sending them over to PayPal for payment.  That way you can send the invoice/order ID in the "invoice" parameter within the PayPal request, and again, that value would be returned in IPN in the "invoice" parameter there.

Either way, you can pull that value and then pull out any additional details you need from your own system within the IPN script.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

One question though, when you say "custom" parameter, do you mean that I shall insert a hidden "input" value in the HTML button of PayPal ? I.e, something like this:
<input="hidden" name="dbUserId" value"1337"/>
Then you mean in my servlet I can do something like this?
String dbId = req.getParameter("dbUserId"); ?

Comment: The actual name of the parameter is called "custom".  You can't make up your own name.

Comment: Ok, just to be clear, in other words I must add this line to my button code?
<input type="custom" value="1337"/> and then retrieve it in my servlet like this:
String value = req.getAttribute("custom");
 ?